# Nodejs and Amazon s3 invalid sha256 calculations

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, sha256, cryptojs

I have this issue with node and amazon s3 when it comes to sha256 encryption. I'm reading my files from the file system using `fs.createReadStream(filename)`.am getting this file in chunks.Then am pushing each chunk into an array. Each chunk consists of 1 *1024 *1024 bytes of data.. when the file has finished getting read, on `readstream.on('end')` am looping through each value in array and encrypting each chunk using sha256. in the process of looping, am also adding axios promises of each loop into an array so that when am finished looping through all the chunks and encrypting each at a time, I'm able to use promise.all to send all the requests. the result of each encrypted chunk is also sent together with the each request as an header . The challenge I've been facing and trying to solve is, whenever a request is made, it gets the calculations of the sha256 from s3 is completely different from what I have . I have tried to solve this and to understand this to no avail. below is my code, what could I be doing wrong ?
this is the error that am getting  :

```
Corrupted chunk received:
File corrupted: Expected SHA jakoz9d12xYjzpWVJQlqYdgPxAuF+LjZ9bQRg0hzmL8=, but calculated SHA 103f77f9b006d9b5912a0da167cf4a8cec60b0be017b8262cd00deb3183f3a8b

 const Encryptsha256 = function(chunksTobeHashed) {
            var crypto = require('crypto');            
            var hash = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(chunksTobeHashed).digest('base64')
            return hash;   
        }

   const upload = async function(uploadFile) {  
            var folderPath = uploadFile.filePath               
            var chunksArray = []

            var uploadFileStream = fs.createReadStream(folderPath, { highWaterMark: 1 * 1024 * 1024, encoding:"base64" })
            uploadFileStream.on('data', (chunk) => {
                chunksArray.push(chunk)
                 // console.log('chunk is ', chunk)
            })

            uploadFileStream.on('error', (error) => {
                console.log('error is ', error)
            })

            // file_id: "2fe44d18-fa94b201-2fe44d18b196-f9066e05a81c"

            uploadFileStream.on('end', async() => {
                //code to get file id was here but removed.since it was not much neccessary to this quiz
                

                var  file_id = "2fe44d18-fa94b201-2fe44d18b196-f9066e05a81c"
                let promises = [];                    

                for (var i in chunksArray) {
                    var Content_SHA256 = Encryptsha256(chunksArray[i])
                    var payload = {
                        body: chunksArray[i],
                    }

                   
                    promises.push(
                        axios.post(
                            `${baseURL}/home/url/upload/${fileId}/chunk/${i}`, payload, {
                                header: {
                                    'Content-SHA256': Content_SHA256,
                                },
                            }
                        )

                    )
                }

                Promise.all(promises).then((response) => {
                        console.log('axios::', response)
                    })
                    .catch((error) => {
                        console.log('request error', error)
                    }) 
              
            })
```

Comment: Try to change encoding from 'base64' to 'utf8' or else Node.js is computing the sha256 value of the base64 string.

Comment: I've done that and it has not worked

Comment: Why don't you use AWS SDK?

Comment: The problem is on the amazon side. They're calculating the sha256 of "{"body":"0TtjdW1lbnR ...rest of the chunk}" which am sending as payload instead of calculate that of the value alone. or , could I be making a mistake in my axios on how am sending the payload ?

Comment: Seem like you are wrong in axios payload and I miss this piece of code, the payload should be just `const payload = chunksArray[i]`

Comment: I've tried that bro. to no avail. I don't know how they are calculating their hash. plus am not so conversant with amazon s3

Comment: AWS is expecting the hash is in base64 format while your hash is in Hex format

Comment: The documentation shows exactly how to calculate the checksum. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonglacier/latest/dev/checksum-calculations.html. It looks like your code fails to concatenate each pair of SHA256 hashes to produce the tree hash.

Comment: Exactly. This is what I was missing. Unfortunately the api document I was using never mentioned this